# curl of a vector orthogonal to vector means that said vector is the gradient of a scalar?

Tags: vector-analysis

First-time poster here. I don't yet know how to typeset. I am working through "Tensors, Differential Forms, and Variational Principles" by Lovelock & Rund. At the top of p156, the assertion is made that **G dot (curl G) = 0** is a necessary and sufficient condition for G being the gradient of a scalar (**G** is a vector field).

Am I correct that this assertion is flawed? The necessary part is true, for if **G** is the gradient of a scalar, then its curl is zero and hence **G dot (curl G)** is indeed zero. However, it's not hard to find an example of a non-zero vector field which is perpendicular to its curl. For instance: if **G = (-y,x,0)**, then **curl G = (0,0,2)** so that **G dot (curl G) = 0**. However, **G** is clearly not the gradient of a scalar, for if it were, its curl would be zero (which it's not).

Thank you.

Comment: while you are right, I am not sure in which context that assertion is made in the book and $\textbf G$  is defined under what constraints. In general what you say is correct. If $\textbf G = \nabla g$ where $g$ is a scalar function, we know it is true that $\nabla \times (\nabla g) = 0$ and then follows the assertion about $\nabla \cdot (\nabla \times \textbf G)$ being a necessary condition.

Comment: I appreciate the corroboration! I'm assuming that in your last sentence you meant G dot (curl G) rather than del dot (curl G).

Comment: Yes that is correct. sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you're right. If $\mathbf{G}$ is the gradient of a smooth function then $\mathbf{G}\cdot (\nabla \times \mathbf{G})=0$, but $\mathbf{G}\cdot(\nabla\times \mathbf{G})=0$ does not imply $\mathbf{G}$ is the gradient of a scalar, as your counterexample shows.

---

**Edit:**

You misquoted the book. They say "is a necessary and sufficient condition that $\mathbf{G}$ be **proportional** to the gradient of a scalar function", and here of course, proportionality means proportional by a function, meaning $\mathbf{G}=f \nabla \phi$ for some functions $f,\phi$. It is easily verified in this case that $\mathbf{G}\cdot (\nabla \times \mathbf{G})=0$; for the converse I'm guessing it requires Frobenius (something which I'm not entirely comfortable with so I can't elaborate too much on that). In your example, let $f(x,y)=-y^2$ and $\phi(x,y)=\frac{x}{y}$. Then, $\mathbf{G}=(-y,x,0)$ is equal to $f\nabla \phi$.

Comment: Ahh, I was vaguely aware that I was perhaps being sneaky when I dropped "proportional to" from my transcription of the sentence in the book. Very cool that you "fixed" my example. Faith in the Dover book is restored. Thanks again!